# Uploaded file details on same page in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, file-upload, struts2

I can upload file using struts2.
    But I want to display details (`Filename`, `filesize`, `filetype`)about uploaded file in struts 2.

I am trying to get details using `<s:property value="myFile" />` tag,
but Is always displays [Object HTMLDocument].

My code is following.

**`uploadfile.jsp`:**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
                pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
            <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
            <!DOCTYPE html>

            <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">

            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="success-image">
                 <s:property value="myFile" />
            <s:head theme="ajax" />
                <s:form id="asset-upload"  name="asset-upload" action="uploadFile.action" method="POST"  theme="ajax" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <s:file name="myFile" label="Upload Image"/>
       <s:submit targets="success-image" showLoadingText="false" indicator="uploading-image" id="asdf"/>
    </s:form>
        </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

    <struts>
        <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
        <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
        <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="1000000000" />

        <package name="default" extends="struts-default,json-default" namespace="/">
            <action name="uploadFile" class="com.isam.struts.uploadFile">
                <result name="success">
                    <param name="myFile">myFile</param>
                 </result>
                <result name="error">login.jsp</result>
            </action>

            <action name="autoCompleterList" class="com.isam.struts.AutoCompleterList">
                <result type="json" />
            </action>
        </package>
    </struts>
```

**`UploadFile.java`:**

```
        package com.isam.struts;

        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.IOException;

        import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

        import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

        public class uploadFile extends ActionSupport {

            private File myFile;
            private String myFileContentType;
            private String myFileFileName;
            private String destPath;


            public String execute() {
                /* Copy file to a safe location */
                destPath = "C:/temp/";

                try {
                    System.out.println("Src File name: " + myFile);
                    System.out.println("Dst File name: " + myFileFileName);

                    File destFile = new File(destPath, myFileFileName);
                    FileUtils.copyFile(myFile, destFile);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return ERROR;
                }

                return SUCCESS;
            }

            public File getMyFile() {
                return myFile;
            }

            public void setMyFile(File myFile) {
                this.myFile = myFile;
            }

            public String getMyFileContentType() {
                return myFileContentType;
            }

            public void setMyFileContentType(String myFileContentType) {
                this.myFileContentType = myFileContentType;
            }

            public String getMyFileFileName() {
                return myFileFileName;
            }

            public void setMyFileFileName(String myFileFileName) {
                this.myFileFileName = myFileFileName;
            }

        }
```

So What I should need to add in jsp file to shows details, 
and what I should need to add in `struts.xml` file

Comment: You are not concrete. Uploaded and uploading is different flow. When do you need to show details about file?

Comment: after uploading file I want to display details about that file.
and also want to display notification like "your file has been successfully uploaded".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show file details on the same page after uploading it change your action result to:

```
<action name="uploadFile" class="com.isam.struts.uploadFile">
   <result name="success">uploadfile.jsp</result>
   <result name="error">login.jsp</result>
</action>
```

And in JSP use `<s:property>` tag to display values:

```
<s:property value="myFile.length()"/>
<s:property value="myFileContentType"/>
<s:property value="myFileFileName"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In `uploadFile` action you need to put setters for info and getters to display it at the result.

```
public void setUpload(File myFile) {
  this.myFile= myFile;
}

public void setUploadContentType(String myFileContentType) {
  this.myFileContentType= myFileContentType;
}

public void setUploadFileName(String myFileFileName) {
  this.myFileFileName = myFileFileName;
}


public String getMyFileFileName() {
  return myFileFileName;
}

public String getMyFileSize() {
  return myFile.length();
}

public String getMyFileContentType() {
  return myFileContentType;
}
```

It has named for injecting values that you could further display with

```
<s:property value="myFileName" />

<s:property value="myFileSize" />

<s:property value="myFileContentType" />
```

If the file has extension, you can check it from  `myFile`. If it has an image type then you should apply codecs to get it and dimensions. However, it isn't needed. After getting the `BufferedImage` you can write or scale to to any image type or size.

What is wrong is the result "success". The result should be the normal URL to the redirect action with param of id image if you want to get it back you have to load it again.