# How to find the extension of uploaded file in java?

Tags: java, struts2, upload

I have the following code to upload the files, when I use the `file.getNeme` it shows the temporary file name that has the `tmp` extension, how can I find the extension of the actual upload file? the file that I am uploading is called `test.jpg`

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class FileUploder {

  private File file;

  public File getFile() {
        return file;
  }

  public void setFile(File file) {
        this.file = file;
  }
   ......

  System.out.println("file:" +file.getName());  
  try {
        File fileToCreate = new File(filePath,name);
        FileUtils.copyFile(file, fileToCreate);
  } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
  }

  ......
```

the current output is similar to >>> `file:upload__1a6d32_13d0eda6d49__7fdf_00000012.tmp`

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/file-upload.html#FileUpload-BasicUsage

Comment: @guido, I am following this tutorial but it is not about extensions, as shown in the question I am not using filename and contenttype variables as they do not work for some reason but the above code works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uploaded file details on same page in Struts2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890193/uploaded-file-details-on-same-page-in-struts2)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should not use `file.getName()`

http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/file-upload.html#FileUpload-BasicUsage

```
setX(File file)  
    The file that contains the content of the uploaded file. This is a temporary file and file.getName() will not return the original name of the file
```

Instead, create another setter `setFileName(String fileName)` should do.

Comment: the link provided for the solution is not opening.
http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/file-upload.html#FileUpload-BasicUsage can someone please assist how can I find the extension of the actual upload file?

Answer (score 0):

```
   private String getImageFileExtendtion (FileItem item) {
        String formatName = "png";
        String fileName = item.getName();
        if (fileName != null && fileName.length() >0) {
            int index = -1;
             for (int i = fileName.length()-1 ; i >=0; i --) {
                 if (fileName.charAt(i)=='.') {
                     index = i;
                     break;
                 }
             }
            if (index >=0 && index < fileName.length() -1) {
                 formatName = fileName.substring(index+1);
            }
        }
        return formatName ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add another getter/setter as below and also remove the getFile() method and it will work

private String fileFileName;

```
public String getFileFileName() {
    return fileFileName;
}

public void setFileFileName(String fileFileName) {
    this.fileFileName = fileFileName;
}
```